# Skip githooks on git push

Tags: git, push, githooks

**Intro:** I recently installed some software which fires on the git `pre-push` hook. Unfortunately there is a mistake in the software, and it crashes on very large commits.

## Is it possible to run an `git push` without triggering the githooks?

That way I don't have to uninstall the githook?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After reading through some of the [githook documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) I found that the `pre-commit` hook could be omitted with the flag `--no-verify`.

Although it was not mentioned, `--no-verify` also works on `git push` :)

Comment: To my confusion, the short option for `--no-verify` on `git commit`, which is `-n`, does something different on `git push`, namely `--dry-run` (which is exactly the opposite: run all the verifications and other checks, and then *don't* push…)